# Printing Excel Workbooks on Different Computers

Tags: excel, printing

I have an Excel workbook shared with other Excel users. When my co-workers and I use our different computers to print the same sheets to PDF, the page breaks differently in the resulting PDF, even though it displays the same in print preview.

We both run Windows 10, Excel 2016, using the same printer driver and printing preferences. I've confirmed the regional settings in our system are the same. No special fonts are included in the workbook. No difference in the AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Excel/XLSTART/.

How can I avoid the layout changes? Is there anything that I might have missed checking? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're both printing the same version of the same document on the same printer, driver, operating system, etc, then you are missing a setting.

Some printer settings are buried pretty deep.  Also, were you using the *Print Preview* or *Page Preview* when you both viewed it?

I suspect you missed a screen of settings somewhere from the image below, likely the `Options...` button in the bottom right, which take you into the Manufacturer's settings dialog(s).

[image: testpage]

Another place to check for settings you may have missed is the control pael.  Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd><sub>Windows Key</sub> and type `printers` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and make sure you double check every setting in that window and all of the sub-dialogs.  Some printers can have hundreds of settings.

If you still can't find a difference, get a third person on a different computer to try printing it.  The odd man out of the three of your print jobs, is likely the one with the different setting!

If still no go, please post screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, Control Panel -> **Display** settings on different computers distort how Excel fits cells onto a page from computer to computer in my experience.

[Windows7 Control Panel Display Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDPbR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Display settings did it for me. I checked language packs, versions, removed and readded the print to pdf driver packs, the works. I was about to clone the working system to the non working system. The non working system had display scaled 125%....